# Need to count specific letters from a search, why does it show as zero? the data is formatted as ntext

Tags: t-sql

[===CLICK ME FOR THE IMAGE OF THE CODE== I need the count to be (3 for example on the first row) but it shows zero, what is wrong with the code, this is ntext which is why it was casted to nvarchar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaOYV.jpg)

I am trying to count the occurrence of the letter 'a' on a column named Description, however using the query below I am getting the result of zero.

SELECT Description, 
(
datalength(Description) - 
datalength(replace(cast(Description as nvarchar(max)), 'a', ''))
)
 /datalength(Description) [a]

FROM Categories

Comment: You need to write the question and post table structure and some sample data in order for any member of the community to be able to help you.

Comment: Largely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am not sure what else do you require the image uploaded has the details and the question is stated on the title and image description.

Answer (score 0):

An int divided by an int will return an int.  Notice the ***1.0**

**Example**

```
Declare @Description nvarchar(max)='Cat in the Hat was never seen'

SELECT @Description, (( datalength(@Description) - datalength(replace(cast(@Description as nvarchar(max)), 'a', '')) )*100) / datalength(@Description) [a]
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)                a
Cat in the Hat was never seen   10
```

Comment: Thanks John, however the result is the same

Comment: how can we get the result of the whole number 3 based on your example?

Comment: @Leej Updated notice the *100  as an int - this will return an int  if you want decimals, just make it *100.0